# How to use DateTime.ParseExact to parse this date format ("May 01st, 1999")?

Tags: c#

I have a regex format for ("May 01st, 1999") as follows:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2}[a-z]{2},\s\d{4}
```

But I need to use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse the same input. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you already have.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` can't interpret things like `st`, `nd`, `rd`, or `th` as far as I know.

Comment: Nobody in the world would ever use "May 01st" - it should be "May 1st".

Answer (score 3):

There is another way you can parse the date (by defining the formats)-

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string providedDate)
{
    DateTime validDate;
    string[] formats = { "MMM dd'st', yyyy", "MMM dd'nd', yyyy", "MMM dd'rd', yyyy", "MMM dd'th', yyyy" };
    var dateFormatIsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
      providedDate,
      formats,
      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
      DateTimeStyles.None,
      out validDate);
    return dateFormatIsValid ? validDate : DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

And use this method to parse the provided date:

```
string strdatetime = "May 02nd, 1999";
DateTime dateTime = ParseDate(strdatetime);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing enough information. I am assuming you have a format that is checked with regex and you can omit the st,nd, rd etc. If you have a format/string format of the date such as in your example.

```
// 1. Remove st,rd,nd etc with regex or string.Replace
string providedDate = "May 01st, 1999";

// 2. Define your format
string dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy";


// 3. Parse
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(providedDate, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate)
{
  parseDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"); // Or do whatever you want
}
```